# ASP.NET MVC 5 - web configuration tool

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to access the security settings in the ASP.NET Web Configuration tool.

I read the MSDN tutorial at : [MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/08/19/asp-net-web-configuration-tool-missing-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx?PageIndex=2#comments)

I also found how to make the tool run from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20555928)

I am getting the following error when I click the 'Security' link on the web config tool page:

> There is a problem with your selected data store. This can be caused by an invalid      server name or credentials, or by insufficient permission. It can also be caused by the role manager feature not being enabled. Click the button below to be redirected to a page where you can choose a new data store.
>
> The following message may help in diagnosing the problem: Unable to connect to SQL Server database.

I did find a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17387549/682869), but the message to diagnose the problem is different in my case.

Can someone please help ?

Thanks.

**Update**:

Didn't resolve the issue yet, but tried it on a different machine.

Before showing the ASP.NET Web Configuration tool page, it asks for username and password. I tried following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21862581/682869), but it still asks for username and password.
Which username and password is required here ?

Thanks.